# Trigger property changed in one ViewModel from another ViewModel (MessagingCenter)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am trying to inform one ViewModel about changes in another ViewModel. For this matter I have tried to use MessagingCenter. However it looks like it does not work for some reason. Could someone drop some light, why I am not able to change colour of Label in one View from another?

HomeViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MessagingCenterApp.ViewModels
{
  public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Home";

      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, Color>(this, "gaugeColor", (sender, arg) =>
      {
        this._gaugeColor = arg;
      });

      this.GaugeColor = Color.White;
    }

    private Color _gaugeColor;
    public Color GaugeColor
    {
      get => _gaugeColor;
      set
      {
        _gaugeColor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

SettingsViewModel.cs:

```
using MessagingCenterApp.Models;
using MessagingCenterApp.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MessagingCenterApp.ViewModels
{
  public class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Settings";
      MessagingCenter.Send<Object, Color>(this, "gaugeColor", Color.FromHex(this.GaugeColor));

    }

    private string _gaugeColor;
    public string GaugeColor
    {
      get => Preferences.Get("GaugeColor", "#17805d");
      set
      {
        Preferences.Set("GaugeColor", value);
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Implementation without separate button:

SettingsViewModel.cs:

```
using MessagingCenterApp.Models;
using MessagingCenterApp.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MessagingCenterApp.ViewModels
{
  public class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public ICommand changeCommand { get; set; }
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Settings";

      GaugeColor = Color.Red;

      changeCommand = new Command(changeColor);
    }

    private void changeColor()
    {
      GaugeColor = Color.FromHex(this.GaugeColorS);

      MessagingCenter.Send<Object, Color>(this, "gaugeColor", GaugeColor);
    }

    private Color _gaugeColor;
    public Color GaugeColor
    {
      get => _gaugeColor;
      set
      {
        _gaugeColor = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private string _gaugeColorS;
    public string GaugeColorS
    {
      get => Preferences.Get("GaugeColor", "#17805d");
      set
      {
        Preferences.Set("GaugeColor", value);
        this.changeColor();
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HomeViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MessagingCenterApp.ViewModels
{
  public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Home";

      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, Color>(this, "gaugeColor", (sender, arg) =>
      {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("received color = " + arg);
        this.GaugeColor = arg;
      });

      this.GaugeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private Color _gaugeColor;
    public Color GaugeColor
    {
      get => _gaugeColor;
      set
      {
        _gaugeColor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is demo app for testing: https://github.com/vadimffe/MessagingCenterApp

Comment: don't you want to send the message when the property is set, not just in the VM constructor?

Comment: @Jason that's correct! I want to send message directly when property has been changed. I have tried to add EventHandler to SettingsViewModel and then subscribe to it in HomeViewModel, but I am probably doing something wrong as creating a new instance of SettingsViewModel in HomeViewModel does not trigger any events. Then I have tried to go with MessagingCenter. Don't know which one is better tho... and if it is EventHandler, then would be glad to understand how to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send a message to another page when the property in current page is reset, you should add a event trigger (for example clicking a 'Button' in page `SettingsPage`. Once the button is clicked,send a message to page `HomePage`).

I simplified your code,and it works properly on my side. You can modify it to suit your needs.

**BaseViewModel.cs**

```
  public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public IDataStore<Item> DataStore => DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<Item>>();

    bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
      get { return isBusy; }
      set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

    string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
      get { return title; }
      set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

       public  bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**HomeViewModel.cs**

```
public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {

        private Color _gaugeColor;
        public Color GaugeColor
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _gaugeColor, value); }

            get { return _gaugeColor; }
        }


        public HomeViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Home";

      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, Color>(this, "gaugeColor", (sender, arg) =>
      {

          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("received color = " + arg);
           this.GaugeColor = arg;
      });

      this.GaugeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    }
```

**SettingsViewModel.cs**

```
 public class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public ICommand changeCommand { get; set; }
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Settings";

      GaugeColor = Color.Red;

      changeCommand = new Command(changeColor);
    }

        private void changeColor(object obj)
        {
            GaugeColor = Color.Yellow;

            MessagingCenter.Send<Object, Color>(this, "gaugeColor", GaugeColor);
        }

        Color  _gaugeColor;
        public Color GaugeColor
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _gaugeColor, value); }

            get { return _gaugeColor; }
        }

    }
```

**SettingsPage.xaml** (here I add Button )

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MessagingCenterApp.Views.SettingsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MessagingCenterApp.ViewModels" 
             Background="#121212"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:SettingsViewModel />
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Color x:Key="Accent">#0d1117</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>


    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label Text="Gauge color:"></Label>
      <Entry Text="{Binding GaugeColor}" Keyboard="Numeric"></Entry>


      <Button  Text="change color"  Command="{Binding changeCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Update:**

> I mean when I type or select new colour on Settings page, I would like
> to see new colour already

For this, you can add `MessagingCenter.Send` in `SettingsViewModel` as follows:

```
    Color  _gaugeColor;
    public Color GaugeColor
    {
        set { 
            
            SetProperty(ref _gaugeColor, value);

            MessagingCenter.Send<Object, Color>(this, "gaugeColor", GaugeColor);
        }

        get { return _gaugeColor; }
    }
```

And if you don't want the Button, you can remove the `Button` in `SettingsPage.xaml`.

Comment: Thank you once again! Can you please check if I got it right for implementation without additional button from my last edit?

Comment: Hi  @HiFo,  when do you want to send message on your `SettingsPage` page without additional button?

Comment: On a colour changed. I mean when I type or select new colour on Settings page, I would like to see new colour already in Box on Home page

Comment: I have updated my answer.You can check it at the bottom of my reply.

Comment: Besides,I don't think it is the proper way to use code like this :                             
    `private string  _gaugeColorS;
    public string GaugeColorS
    {
      get => Preferences.Get("GaugeColor", "#17805d");
      set
      {
        Preferences.Set("GaugeColor", value);
        this.changeColor();
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }` .  You can refer to my code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! What if I would like to have multiple properties that would update. Do I need to create own MessagingCenter Send and Subscribe for each one or they can be grouped somehow? Let's say I have a GaugeColor, GaugeEndValue, GaugeStartValue etc. properties, each with own type?

Comment: To tell the truth, we do not recommend using MessagingCenter too much. And it is necessary to unsubscribe from a message when a class no longer wishes to receive the message.

Comment: What are the usage scenarios for all these attributes? Can you describe it in detail? We can help you to choose a better method.

Comment: I want to have Settings page with bunch of settings, approximately 20 or 30. Then I would like to use these settings across application in different ViewModels

Comment: One problem, one thread. You can create a new thread for the new problem.  We are all willing to help you.